# Error : Only quota configs can be added for 'clients' using --bootstrap-server. Unexpected config names: Set('producer_byte_rate)

Tags: apache-kafka, throttling

I am trying to set Producer and Consumer quotas in Kafka. I have started zookeeper and kafka server and am trying to change Kafka config

```
`bin\windows\kafka-configs.bat  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --alter --add-config 'producer_byte_rate=1024,consumer_byte_rate=2048,request_percentage=200' --entity-type clients --entity-default`
```

It shows me :

```
Only quota configs can be added for 'clients' using --bootstrap-server. Unexpected config names: Set('producer_byte_rate)
```

Answer (score 1):

using the binaries of Kafka for Windows - you need to use without the " ' "

```
 bin\windows\kafka-configs.bat  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --alter --add-config producer_byte_rate=1024,consumer_byte_rate=2048,request_percentage=200 --entity-type clients --entity-default
 Completed updating default config for clients in the cluster.
```

or using with " "

```
kafka-configs.bat  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --alter --add-config "producer_byte_rate=1024,consumer_byte_rate=2048,request_percentage=200" --entity-type clients --entity-default 
Completed updating default config for clients in the cluster.
```